# Pop up form depending on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I would like a pop up form named 'Question' to show up when a value in cell A9 in worksheet called 'Calculator' matches one of the values in Column O in Worksheet 'Data'.Values. In cell A9 are results of formula.

This code works but when I have other Excel workbooks open, it gives me 'Subscript out of range error'. I would like it to apply to this one particular workbook and not affect the other workbooks I have open.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

If IsError(Application.Match(Range("A9").Value, Sheets("Data").Columns("O"), 0)) Then Exit Sub

If Application.Match(Range("A9").Value, Sheets("Data").Columns("O"), 0) Then
    Question.Show
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")` or it will default to the active workbook

Comment: Thanks Tim, I revised the code using your instructions. So far so good. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the code reference only the workbook that the code is stored in:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    With ThisWorkbook
        If IsError(Application.Match(.ActiveSheet.Range("A9").Value, .Sheets("Data").Columns("O"), 0)) Then Exit Sub
        If Application.Match(.ActiveSheet.Range("A9").Value, .Sheets("Data").Columns("O"), 0) Then
            Question.Show
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

...It would be good to replace `ActiveSheet` with a specific sheet reference.

Comment: Within the worksheet code module, `Me` will always refer to the sheet itself.  It's not a good idea to use `ActiveSheet` here, since that could well be a different sheet.